# PHP - Split string

Tags: php

I want to split this string up into parts like "Source: Web", "Pics: 1" ... to use it within my website.
From the "Lat:" and "Lon:" I need to extract just the numbers.

```
    <cap>
Source: Web | Pics: 1 | Frame: 2 | Date: 4-25-2011 | On: App | Lat: 51.2222 | Lon: 7.6555
</cap>
```

What's the best way to do it? I read about explode() but I don't get it to work.
Cheers

Comment: Maybe you should clarify whether you mean the string includes all the shown text, including <cap> tags, or only the inner text inside the <cap> tags, as some are taking the tags into account and some do not.

Comment: Come on. Using the title of your post I get a [ton of answers to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+split). Also, go back and accept some previous answers or cease asking them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a bit of code I whipped up using `explode` ([DEMO](http://codepad.org/ePwf0TFD))

```
<?php    
    $str = "Source: Web | Pics: 1 | Frame: 2 | Date: 4-25-2011 | On: App | Lat: 51.2222 | Lon: 7.6555";
    $arr = explode(" | ", $str);
    foreach ($arr as $item){
        $arr2 = explode(": ", $item);
        $finalArray[$arr2[0]]=$arr2[1];
    }
    print_r($finalArray);
?>
```

**RESULT**

```
Array
(
    [Source] => Web
    [Pics] => 1
    [Frame] => 2
    [Date] => 4-25-2011
    [On] => App
    [Lat] => 51.2222
    [Lon] => 7.6555
)
```

**USAGE**

```
echo $finalArray['Lon']; //yields '7.6555'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a ridiculous one-liner that should probably never be used, but it uses no loops (i hate loops). I also like to practice my REs

```
$str = 'Source: Web | Pics: 1 | Frame: 2 | Date: 4-25-2011 | On: App | Lat: 51.2222 | Lon: 7.6555';
preg_match( sprintf( '~%s~', implode(array_map( function($val){ if ($val) return sprintf( '%1$s:\s(?P<%1$s>.*?)(?:(?:\s\|\s)|(?:$))', $val ); }, preg_split( '~:.*?(?:(?:\s\|\s)|(?:$))~', $str ) ) ) ), $str, $m );
print_r($m);
```

result

```
Array
(
    [Source] => Web
    [Pics] => 1
    [Frame] => 2
    [Date] => 4-25-2011
    [On] => App
    [Lat] => 51.2222
    [Lon] => 7.6555
)
```

Comment: Holy convolution, Batman!  Would you really write or advise that to be used in a professional application?

Answer (score 0):

```
$pieces = explode(' | ','Source: Web...'); //Rest of string in there.
$items = array();
foreach ($pieces as $piece) {
    $parts = explode(': ', $piece);
    $items[$parts[0]] = $parts[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "Source: Web | Pics: 1 | Frame: 2 | Date: 4-25-2011 | On: App | Lat: 51.2222 | Lon: 7.6555";
$pieces = explode("|", $string);
print_r($pieces);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$items = explode(' | ', "Source: Web | Pics: 1 | Frame: 2 | Date: 4-25-2011 | On: App | Lat: 51.2222 | Lon: 7.6555");

foreach ($items as $item) {
   $new_data = explode(': ', $item);
   $my_array[$new_data[0]] = $new_data[1];
}

print_r($my_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It will split them and create an associative array:

```
$string = 'Source: Web | Pics: 1 | Frame: 2 | Date: 4-25-2011 | On: App | Lat: 51.2222 | Lon: 7.6555';
$list = explode('|', $string);
$assoc = array();
foreach($list as $part) {
    list($key, $val) = explode(':', $part);
    $assoc[trim($key)] = trim($val);
}

print_r($assoc);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$val =<<<END
<cap>
    Source: Web | Pics: 1 | Frame: 2 | Date: 4-25-2011 | On: App | Lat: 51.2222 | Lon: 7.6555
</cap>
END;

$bits = split("[:|]", $val);
$lat = trim($bits[11]);
$lon = trim($bits[13]);
```

Comment: This will give you an array mixed with Keys **and** values. Poor form.

Comment: But +1 for using Heredoc syntax ^^

Comment: How does that contribute at all to the question :)

Comment: It _may_ contribute s/t, because it's the only answer taking the <cap> tags into account by now. It's not clear whether the OP wanted to split inclusive or exclusive <cap> tags. But I of course agree that the splitting part is not, what I'd do^^

Comment: Ah, @Dutchie432, did you actually run the code: it returns this: array(14) { [0]=> string(16) " Source" [1]=> string(5) " Web " [2]=> string(5) " Pics" [3]=> string(3) " 1 " [4]=> string(6) " Frame" [5]=> string(3) " 2 " [6]=> string(5) " Date" [7]=> string(11) " 4-25-2011 " [8]=> string(3) " On" [9]=> string(5) " App " [10]=> string(4) " Lat" [11]=> string(9) " 51.2222 " [12]=> string(4) " Lon" [13]=> string(14) " 7.6555 " }. All he cared about (from his question) is extracting lat/lon: the prettiness of mixed key/values seems kinda secondary.

Comment: I don't need to run the code, I can tell (as I previously stated) exactly what you will end up with. Who wants to retrieve their values by alternating numerical values? Seems that you're making much more work for the coder. `$array['lon']` is MUCH easier than `$array[11]` unless you can remember what each number represents. Again, I will restate, this is NEVER a preferable method.

Comment: Well, if you truly want to burn cycles, you can always build an array with string keys, but that just seems excessive: $j = count($bits); for($i=0;$i<$j;$i+=2) $final[$bits[$i]] = $bits[$i+1]; $lat = trim($final['lat']); $lon = trim($final['lon']);

Answer (score -1):

You are correct.  [explode](http://ca.php.net/explode) is the best function for this.

Comment: This really isn't a good answer. From his question, he knows about explode() but couldn't get it to function properly. If you're going to suggest that he use it, you should provide an example, as did every other answer. ;)

Comment: Thank you guys for the many examples and infos. I really appreciate it!