# Split string into words in php

Tags: php, regex

I want to split string which contains braces 
e.g.

```
string = "some-thing_text,text in rounded brackets(word first,word second),Text in curly brackets{some-text(some one,some two),some another},Text in square brackets[some text,some another{some like this(this1,this2)}]"
```

and output will be :

```
Array
(
    [0] => some-thing_text
    [1] => text in rounded brackets(word first,word second)
    [2] => Text in curly brackets{some-text(some one,some two),some another}
    [3] => Text in square brackets[some text,some another{some like this(this1,this2)}]
)
```

Comment: At the moment, it seems you could simply use `explode(",", $string);` that is exploding the string by a colon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Split string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782027/php-split-string)

Comment: Explode it just like they say.

Comment: simply exploding the string by comma will include the the commas inside the braces so it won't do

Answer (score 3):

```
,(?![^{]*})(?![^(]*\))(?![^\[]*\])
```

You can use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/lR1eC9/8

Answer (score 1):

You may try this,

```
preg_split('~(?:\[.*?\]|\(.*?\)|\{.*?\})(*SKIP)(*F)|,~', $str);
```

- `(?:\[.*?\]|\(.*?\)|\{.*?\})` matches all the bracketed blocks.
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` makes the previous match to fail.
- `,` Now it matches comma from the remaining string.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lR1eC9/9)

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_split('~,(?![^{]*}|[^(]*\)|[^\[]*\])~', $string)
```